# Solve this summation for a closed form

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$h_n = \sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{-n}{n-k}  \binom{n}{k}}$$

I've tried turing the negative to a positive using the identity but I get nonsense after. I summed them together but you get $\binom{0}{n}$. I am not sure what else to do. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What is the $n$th coefficient in the Maclaurin series of $(1 + x)^{ - n} (1 + x)^n$ if you consider the Cauchy product of the Maclaurin series of each of the two factors?

Comment: "using the identity" if you can specify the details of this identity, it will be nice. Also, basically this is the Chu-Vandermonde identity as in [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vandermondes-identity/#:~:text=Chu%2DVandermonde's%20Identity%3A&text=(nx%2By%E2%80%8B),)%20(%20x%20%E2%88%92%202%20)%20%E2%80%A6) with $m+n=0$ and $k=n$, so you are correct in your evaluation and there is not much else to do, unless you need a different kind of proof or need convincing that $\binom{0}{n}$ is "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sum is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), so you can ask a computer to find a closed form for you. See the book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) for more information. In the short term, you can ask [sage](https://sagemath.org) for instance, and it will tell you the answer is $0$. This agrees with your computation that the answer is $\binom{0}{n} = 0$, unless $n=0$, in which case the $\binom{0}{0} = 1$. This agrees, moreover, with the answer suggested by @Gary's hint in the comments.

---

I hope this helps ^_^